# Is HTTP to HTTPS redirection configurable per frontend in the Træfik File backend?

Tags: traefik

According to https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/2133, it should be possible to redirect selectively per frontend. Is this available in the File backend?

I tried adding the following, but it didn't work:

`[frontends.foo.headers]
SSLRedirect = true`

Answer (score 0):

The option `SSLRedirect = true` always redirect on 443.
If you want to redirect to an entry point without using 443 port use `entryPoint = "https"`

https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/examples/#http-redirect-on-https

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
      certFile = "examples/traefik.crt"
      keyFile = "examples/traefik.key"
```

https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/file/

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  # ...
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  # ...

[file]

[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
  backend = "backend1"
    [frontends.frontend1.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"

# ...
```

Comment: Isn't this the config for redirecting all requests? I need to be able to either disable it for certain frontends, or disable it generally, and selectively enable it.

Comment: It's the same approach for a frontend: https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/file/#reference